# Unresolved reference DaggerApplicationComponent when trygin to build app component

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

I'm usign Android Studio  2022.3.1 Patch 2, I'm trying to create my app component, but Dagger does not generate my app component. Here it is the MainApplication.kt

```
class MainApplication : Application() {

    val applicationComponent: ApplicationComponent =
        DaggerApplicationComponent.builder().applicationModule(ApplicationModule(this)).build()

    @Inject
    lateinit var indoor: Indoor

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        applicationComponent.inject(this)
    }
}
```

And my ApplicationComponent

```
import dagger.Component
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
@Component(modules = [ApplicationModule::class])
interface ApplicationComponent {
    @ApplicationContext
    fun context(): Context
    fun application(): Application
    fun  inject(application: MainApplication)
}
```

Also in my build.graddle, the dependencies looks like this

```
//Dagger
    implementation("com.google.dagger:dagger:2.48.1")
    implementation("com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.48.1") 
    annotationProcessor("com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.48.1")
    annotationProcessor("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.48.1")
```

I tried using

kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.x.x

But it didnt work

Edit: This is my ApplicationModule code

```
import dagger.Module
```

import dagger.Provides
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module
class ApplicationModule (private val application: Application) {

```
@Provides
@ApplicationContext
fun provideContext(): Context = application

@Provides
fun provideApplication(): Application = application
```

Comment: add please code of `ApplicationModule`. Also I think you have some crossed logic. Move `fun context(): Context` and `fun application(): Application` into `ApplicationModule`

Comment: @hi.cosmonaut HI, I edited the question with my ApplicationModule code, also I'm going to try to do that and move the context and the fun application

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your `ApplicationModule`

```
@Module 
class ApplicationModule (private val application: Application) {

@Provides
fun provideApplication(): Application = application

}
```

Double check if `Indoor` class has `@Inject` annotated constructor:

```
class Indoor @Inject constructor(...){
    ...
}
```

And `ApplicationComponent` :

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [ApplicationModule::class])
interface ApplicationComponent {
    fun inject(application: MainApplication)
}
```

**ALSO**
You can pass `Indoor` into object graph by `ApplicationModule`

```
@Module 
class ApplicationModule (private val application: Application) {

@Provides
fun provideApplication(): Application = application
    
@Provides
//@Singleton
fun provideIndoor(application: Application) = Indoor(application)

}
```